# Control internet in windows7 64bit

Tags: python, windows

I want control internet on or off in python.

Is it possible ?

This is pseudocode:

```
if a < 0:
 internet on
if a > 0:
 internet off
```

Comment: Using ctypes you can get access to the win32 API from Python and control that.

Comment: "Internet on" and "Internet off" don't mean much... It's clear-ish only if you are on dial up, otherwise what do you want to do, shut down the WiFi connection? Disable the wired ethernet card?

Comment: i wanna disable ethernet card and enable ethernet card(network card)